# Filter Nifi Flowfile Payload json using json array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have been trying to filter out just the required attributes from the payload. The required attributes could be passed as an array or added to the existing payload.

I was looking for transform via **Apache Nifi JoltTransform processor** but how to filter the fields dynamically according to the filter array field names is unclear.

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "payload": {
    "code": "123-ABC2",
    "code3": "123-ABC3",
    "code2": "123-ABC"
  },
  "keys": [
    {
      "key": "code"
    },
    {
      "key": "code2"
    }
  ]
}
```

The final payload should be like this:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "payload": {
    "code": "123-ABC2",
    "code2": "123-ABC"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "&",
      "keys": {
        "*": { // 0, 1
          "*": { // key
            "*": { // code, code2
              "@(5,payload.&)": "payload.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Update:**

As you can see in the below image. We are using the `code` and `code2` in the `key` with `&` to access value of `payload.code` and `payload.code2`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works but could you please add why did you have go inside thrice into keys and back 5 with @

Comment: @Scorpy Your welcome. **0.** `root`, **1.** `keys`, **2.** indexes of the array, **3.** `key`, **4.** values of the key, **5.** using `@` for getting value and setting our condition on it. Answer updated with comments for better understanding.

Comment: @Scorpy Answer updated. I add an image to my answer. I hope it is useful.

Comment: @MohmmadReza really greatful for this explanation. But is there some tutorial over this, I have just seen on basic transforms. but this way of entering into the tree and 5 levels up tree to get the payload value is not yet clear for me. Is it because of the json array ? If it was just "keys" : { "key1": "value1", "key2":"value2"}, then to reach value1 it would be "@(4, payload.&)" : payload.& ?

Comment: @Scorpy Right. in this case, you remove **2. indexes of the array**. So you should go 1 level less.